# Set a maximum time for the connection attempt (Socket)

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection

I'm trying to set a maximum time for the connection attempt. I've tried to `sleep(5000)` and then `if(!socket.isConnected)`. Unfortunately it didn't work.
How can I do this?

Code:

```
                try {

                    socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, PORT);
                    socket.setSoTimeout(500);

                    Boolean isDone = false;
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();                // Socketstream holen
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);       // Socket lesen

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);             // In Buffer

                    String msg;

                                                              // Erstelle den String msg

                    while (!isDone && ((br.readLine()) != null)) {     
                        // Do stuff

                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(Bedienung.this)
                                    .setTitle("Fehler bei der Verbindung")
                                    .setMessage("Es konnte keine Verbindung mit " + SERVER_IP + " auf " + PORT + " hergestellt werden!")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Wiederholen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();

                                            Socket.read(sharedPref);

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
```

Here's the code now. Hope it will help you

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `setSOTimeout` method

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `Socket` using `Socket(String, int)`, it'll automatically attempt to connect. There is no way to set a connection timeout using that constructor.

Instead, use the nullary constructor `Socket()`, and connect using the `connect` method. This method lets you specify a timeout for the connection:

```
 InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 15180);
 Socket socket = new Socket();
 int timeout = 10000;

 socket.connect(address, timeout);
```

If you want to time-out read() calls that take too long, use `setSOTimeout`

Comment: @Baldoius No, you would create a new `InetSocketAddress`, using the host and port for the parameters: `socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));` I suggest storing the `InetSocketAddress` somewhere so it can be re-used if needed. If you look at the code for the `Socket` constructor, you'll notice that it actually creates a `InetSocketAddress` and invokes `connect`, so it does the same thing we're doing here (create address using host and port, then connect). Not sure why they don't have a constructor which allows you to set the timeout

Comment: @Baldoius I'm not sure what you're referring to. Is it related to the timeout?

Comment: @Baldoius I don't understand your problem; your English is a little off. "I also become an IOException" doesn't make sense to me. Please be more detailed with the problem you are having. Also, update the code in your question